# aggregating multiple ISP connections

Tags: isp, connections

OK, so we have an office in Pakistan. Phone and ISP service is pretty poor there, so they have 2 ISP connections, one thru Pakistan telecom, one thru a different ISP. The PK tele one has a router that cannot be changed (so they tell me), the other one connects to a local service over RJ45.

So assuming the routers cannot be swapped out, how can I configure the office so that some level of fail-over is provided, and the office all connects to one network, with one dhcp provider, giving them somewhat robust internet access without split networks, and having to mess around if a connection goes down.

I have access to a spare Ubuntu box if needed to be set up as a proxy server or similar. We can add NIC's to this.

Comment: I really feel so sorry for you :/

Comment: While sympathy is always much appreciated, that hasn't exactly moved me forwards ;)

Comment: Could you update us with the solution you went with? Provide the solution and accept it. That way it will help us all in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use two nics, use iproute2 to create source based routing in ubuntu. There are a lot of iproute2 dual wan guides on the internet.

Comment: I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

und linux this is possible but it's a good load of reading trying and testing.

you have a spare box. This is good put 3 Nics in it and the use the BSD [**pfsense**](http://www.pfsense.org/) Distro.

it's a really good bsd firewall distro with tons of good features and free :)

for you the [**Multi WAN**](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN_2.0) setup.

Loadbalancing and FailOver scenarios are no problem and working like a charm.

cheers

Comment: Looks good, investigating now.